# Reference SVG file in CSS of custom plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I have built a custom plugin and have a css file that is being injected as an assetbundle.
This works great but when I want to set a background image (SVG in this case) I'm not sure what the path should be.
I would like to store the SVG inside the plugin folder and not in the main project.
Should I store the SVG in the resources folder or create a web folder like some other plugins seem to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working thanks to the awesome Craft CMS support.

As explained in the question I already had my CSS and JS files registered and working in the plugin.
The assetbundle's sourcePath is `@vendor/plugin_handle/resources/dist/`
So I had to move my SVG inside the dist folder.

Then in the css file I just had to adjust the path to the SVG relative to the css file. In my case it was `../img/icon.svg`

Answer (score 0):

For assets (images, CSS, JS) stored in your plugin's source folder, you'll need a *published file URL* to use them in front-end or control panel templates.

Essentially, in "publishing" a file, Craft will copy it to the `cpresources` folder under your web root - meaning that it's eventual URL will be something like `https://foo.ddev.site/cpresources/1sdfasz/icon.svg`.

Assuming your icon lives in a `resources` folder inside your plugin, here's how to do it in PHP and Twig, respectively:

```php
$url = \Craft::$app->assetManager->getPublishedUrl(
    '@vendor/plugin/resources/icon.svg',
    true
);
```

```
{% set iconUrl = craft.app.assetManager.getPublishedUrl('@vendor/plugin/resources/icon.svg', true) %}
```

Note that the `'@vendor/plugin'` part should be replaced with your plugin's *auto-generated* Yii alias.

See [the official docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/asset-bundles.html#getting-published-file-urls) for more info!